# AWS Private Subnet - Security Group Rules?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I had originally setup an AWS VPC with Public and Private Subnets, and fairly stringent Security Group ingress rules for the instances in the Private Subnets (rds, load-balanced-ec2 instances, elasticache, ec2 worker instances).

For example, the ingress rules for my RDS secruity group entailed explicitly declaring each security group that was allowed access to the DB (load-balanced-ec2 instances, workers instances, etc)

As I was refactoring, it occurred to me that because these instances are in a private subnet, and don't have access to an Internet Gateway, could I in-fact get away with a simpler set of ingress rules?  Maybe, something where any instance within the VPC has TCP access to the Private Subnet?  This would simply my configuration setup with Terraform as well.

Or is a better practice to have a more explicit set of rules?

Comment: The question you should ask yourself is: do you trust all the apps that are running in the VPC completely. If you have a big team and loads of apps that are deployed all the time, some extra layer of security might not be a bad idea. If it's a small setup and you're fairly certain the apps don't do anything stupid; in that case I would say allowing all internal VPC traffic is not a bad idea per se.

Comment: @Bram Right, I see.  Currently, my application is the only one in the VPC (and for the foreseeable future).  You specify this just by providing the VPC CIDR block, right?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: The approach I would recommend is using the [default VPC security group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html#DefaultSecurityGroup). That group allows traffic from all other resources that have the group assigned, so you can allow internal traffic without caring about IP ranges.

Comment: Why not allow everything in your VPC CIDR or everything in private subnet and few more from public subnet?